# Why "hedging motives" and "heterogeneous preferences" are explanation for "under diversification puzzle"?

Tags: hedging, financial-markets, investment, diversification

[Han et al. 2021](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-financial-and-quantitative-analysis/article/social-transmission-bias-and-investor-behavior/72313DD8E8227F179EE1ED760B10FD65) documented something relating to the "under diversification puzzle":

> Standard explanations for under diversification include hedging motives
> and heterogeneous preferences, but several studies highlight the
> limitations of these explanations

From [Statman, 2004](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/4480587.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A7464a6fc03f9b2dc7b14f9a6efd59a7b), I understand that "**under diversification puzzle**" is normally, we should hold a portfolio of around 300 stocks but in U.S, the average investor hold is only 3 or 4 stocks.

I understand that "**hedging motives**" is that risk aversion, meaning investors need to buy some stocks to reduce the risk of the portfolio. "**heterogeneous preference**" is that each individual investor has their own risk preference.
However, given the understanding above, I **cannot understand why we can use "hedging motives" and "heterogeneous preferences" to explain the "underdiversification puzzle"**

Comment: Hi Louise, i remember Mitton, Boyer and Vorkink wrote an explanation by setting up a model on how heterogeneity in preferences might impact diversification decisions: https://www.jstor.org/stable/4494802... Let me know if this is helpful, then i post a full-fledged answer :-)

Comment: Dear @T123J, it would be a big help that you can post an answer that can benefit me and other readers who may have the same problems with me :D. Thanks a heap

Comment: Consumer Hedging motives for investment were discussed years ago by R.C.Merton. A (contrived) example is an automobile owner who could buy Exxon stock to hedge against increases in price of gasoline.

Comment: @noob2, if they buy more stocks to hedge, it would increase the number of stocks being held, leading to better diversification rather than underdiversification?

Comment: Not necessarily. If they *only* care about hedging, they could end up with a very strange portfolio, 100% XOM stock, or to hedge inflation 100% Gold. Very undiversified.